# Shiny, creating and rendering a table using a self written function

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to simulate data of a rating scale and then have the data rendered in shiny.  I tried every possible solution I could think of for 2 days, but cannot figure it...
I believe it is the "clutchy" programming of the function I made that causes it. Specifically that no "input" dependent variable is used when creating the column names, but very unsure about it and even more about how to work around this.

It is supposed to be included in a wider program that will create various tables for demographics and measures, and then create outputs based on them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(PearsonDS)


sim_CAINS <- function(su_n,hc_n) {
  
  CAINS <- tibble(
    sub_id = numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationfam =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationsoc =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivation_Work =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationrec =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionfac =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionvoc =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressiongest =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionspeechquant =numeric())
  ##sampling for service users
  for ( id in 1:su_n) {
    CAINS <- CAINS %>% add_row(
      sub_id = id,
      CAINS_Motivationfam = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.27, 1.09, .49,3))),
      CAINS_Motivationsoc = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.67, 1.24, .33,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.52, 1.43, .33,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.44, 1.45, .40,3))),
      CAINS_Motivation_Work = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(2.03, 1.44, .02,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(2.80, 1.29, -.86,3))),
      CAINS_Motivationrec = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.03, 1.02, .72,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.50, 1.03, .19,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(.90, 1.26, 1.07,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionfac = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.56, 1.10, .31,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionvoc = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.10, 1.13, .71,3))),
      CAINS_Expressiongest = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.52, 1.25, .34,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionspeechquant = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(0.75, .93, 1.03,3))))
    
  }
  ##replace values that are too small or too big
  CAINS[2:14] <- CAINS[2:14] %>% replace(CAINS[2:14]<0,0) %>% replace(CAINS[2:14]>4,4)
  
  ##sampling for healthy controls
  for ( id in (1+su_n):(su_n+hc_n)) {
    CAINS <- CAINS %>% add_row(
      sub_id = id,
      CAINS_Motivationfam = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivationsoc = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivation_Work = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivationrec = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionfac = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionvoc = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressiongest = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionspeechquant = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)))
    
  }
  
  return(CAINS)
}
 
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Negative Symptom Simulator"),
    
    # Sidebar with a number input for service users and healthy controls 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h3("Participant Numbers"),
            numericInput("nSU", label = h5("Service Users"), value = 20),
            numericInput("nHC", label = h5("Healthy Controls"), value = 20),
            
            actionButton("update", "Update")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
              
                tabPanel("CAINS", plotOutput("tableCAINS")) 

                         
                )
            )
        )
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


  
  
  

      
      storage <- reactiveValues()
    
    

  
    observeEvent(input$update, {
        
      observe({
        storage$dataCAINS <-sim_CAINS(input$nSU,input$nHC)
        
      })

        
        
    })
    
    
    
    
    output$tableCAINS <- renderTable(storage$dataCAINS)
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent`. And you should use `tableOutput` instead of `plotOutout` when using `renderTable`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(PearsonDS)


sim_CAINS <- function(su_n,hc_n) {
  
  CAINS <- tibble(
    sub_id = numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationfam =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationsoc =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivation_Work =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Motivationrec =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionfac =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionvoc =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressiongest =numeric(),
    CAINS_Expressionspeechquant =numeric())
  ##sampling for service users
  for ( id in 1:su_n) {
    CAINS <- CAINS %>% add_row(
      sub_id = id,
      CAINS_Motivationfam = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.27, 1.09, .49,3))),
      CAINS_Motivationsoc = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.67, 1.24, .33,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.52, 1.43, .33,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.44, 1.45, .40,3))),
      CAINS_Motivation_Work = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(2.03, 1.44, .02,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(2.80, 1.29, -.86,3))),
      CAINS_Motivationrec = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.03, 1.02, .72,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.50, 1.03, .19,3))),
      CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(.90, 1.26, 1.07,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionfac = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.56, 1.10, .31,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionvoc = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.10, 1.13, .71,3))),
      CAINS_Expressiongest = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(1.52, 1.25, .34,3))),
      CAINS_Expressionspeechquant = round(rpearson(1, moments = c(0.75, .93, 1.03,3))))
    
  }
  ##replace values that are too small or too big
  CAINS[2:14] <- CAINS[2:14] %>% replace(CAINS[2:14]<0,0) %>% replace(CAINS[2:14]>4,4)
  
  ##sampling for healthy controls
  for ( id in (1+su_n):(su_n+hc_n)) {
    CAINS <- CAINS %>% add_row(
      sub_id = id,
      CAINS_Motivationfam = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivationsoc = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_lastweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasure_Social_nextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivation_Work = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasureworknextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Motivationrec = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasurereclastweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Pleasurerecnextweek = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionfac = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionvoc = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressiongest = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)),
      CAINS_Expressionspeechquant = sample(0:2,1,F,c(.7,.2,.1)))
    
  }
  
  return(CAINS)
}

shinyApp(
  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Negative Symptom Simulator"),
    
    # Sidebar with a number input for service users and healthy controls
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h3("Participant Numbers"),
        numericInput("nSU", label = h5("Service Users"), value = 20),
        numericInput("nHC", label = h5("Healthy Controls"), value = 20),
        
        actionButton("update", "Update")
      ),
      
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          
          tabPanel("CAINS", tableOutput("tableCAINS"))
          
          
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
  
    storage$dataCAINS <- eventReactive(input$update, {
      
      sim_CAINS(input$nSU,input$nHC)
        
    })
    
    output$tableCAINS <- renderTable(storage$dataCAINS())

})
```